# Subquery in FROM clause with multiple column result

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm looking for a way to transform this query into the Django queryset equivalent:

```
SELECT a.name, b.num_something FROM table_a a, 
(SELECT id, COUNT(id) as num_something FROM table_b
 GROUP BY id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) b 
WHERE a.id=b.id;
```

The keys of table_a and table_b are not connected by FK constraint (and it's something that I cannot touch, not my part of the code), but the values represent a relationship between table_a and table_b.

I've managed to get a subquery retrieving results according to my needs. Now I don't get the part of embedding it into the main query (obviously if ORM permits doing it). My actual query looks like:

```python
Something.objects.values_list(
    'id').annotate(
        num_something=Count('id')).order_by(
            '-num_something')[:10]
```

**EDIT**
The reason why I don't want to use raw SQL query is mainly because the fact that I'm not sure that MySQL is the database which will be always used with software. This query would not work with Oracle for example.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you don't use [raw](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/)?

```
Something.objects.raw(
    'SELECT a.name, b.num_something '
    'FROM table_a a, (SELECT id, COUNT(id) as num_something '
    '                 FROM table_b '
    '                 GROUP BY id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) b '
    'WHERE a.id=b.id')
```

Comment: Hey, I guess that If I'll use raw, my code may break when someone will change the database from MySQL to Oracle(for example), where for instance LIMIT does not exist (at least at version 10).. There are other ways to limit results in Oracle.